# In "Revolt in the Stars", why did Xenu decide to destroy the excess aliens?

Tags: l-ron-hubbard, revolt-in-the-stars

In L.Ron Hubbard's screenplay "[Revolt in the Stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolt_in_the_Stars)", it says Xenu was about to lose power but **it doesn't give reason as to how this achieved his goal**. He killed billions of aliens. It would seem to be something very unpopular to do.

You can read a full first draft of the screenplay [here](http://www.simplyscripts.com/scripts/RevoltintheStars.pdf), as written by Harley Wolfe Jr.

Comment: I would answer, but my OT3 level has an NDA like you wouldn't believe.

Comment: +1 if you are joking... but I'll back away awkwardly if not and then run.

Comment: [We at the FBI do not have a sense of humor we're aware of](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119654/quotes?qt=qt0402557).

Comment: Much as I think Scientology is silly, I think this may be skirting a little close to our policy against discussion of religion. I'm not voting to close yet, but I have [opened a discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2559/do-works-from-l-ron-hubbard-that-are-part-of-scientology-canon-count-as-relig). In particular, I'm concerned that *Revolt in the Stars* is, afaik, unpublished, so it is hard to determine if your question is really about the screenplay, or about the core beliefs of Scientology.

Comment: @Beofett I am just curious in general. I enjoy stories of all kinds, whether they are of fictional origin or of fictional origin with a pretense. If you feel it is offensive, I'm not offended if you remove it.

Comment: @zipstory.com I'm not at all offended by it.  However, we, as a community, should be wary of anything that could offend someone's sincerely held beliefs. For background, we had some questions at one point about bible stories, that some Christians felt were offensive (iirc, part oft he problem was that the [tag:magic] tag was used), which led to [this discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/should-we-exclude-religious-texts-and-which). I'm not convinced your question falls into the "religious" category, but it is close enough that I feel it merits some discussion.

Comment: @Beofett to rephrase, you make a great point and you can remove it without my protest.

Comment: I do wish the burden of proof meant something.

Comment: @zipstory.com - **Everyone else's religions** always sound weird.

Comment: Especially when you have no religion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The murders were a [false-flag attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_flag) instigated by Xenu to kill his enemies, cleanse the planets of people that he considers "undesirable" and to provide a pretext to take greater control of the Galactic Defence Force.

After having glanced through what I can only describe as one of the **[worst](http://www.simplyscripts.com/scripts/RevoltintheStars.pdf)** screenplays I've ever read, I think I've found the section you're referring to;

1. Xenu's GDF troops (led by their psychiatrist officers) evacuate; "*all citizens who are in the Field of the Arts, education, Journalism, religious leaders, civil liberty activists, or those who are unemployed*" from the planet Procyon and transport them to the planet Teegeeack.
2. They collect troops that are loyal to the government and transport them to the same planet.
3. They use a "*451 MX EXPLOSIVE DEVICE. The most powerful atomic bomb ever made*" to blow them all up, then blame the Grey Invaders;

> "**News Reporter :** This is truly a sad day. We are just receiving breaking news from the
>   Galactic Defense Force that Teegeeack has just suffered a full scale
>   assault from the Grey invaders. Resulting in the death of Commander
>   Rawl, leader of Teegeeack.
>
> Xenu is said to be distraut [sic] after learning of Rawls death and the
>   attack on Teegeeack and has sworn to redouble his efforts to defend
>   the Confederation.

Comment: I think that deserves a +1 for services and sacrifices above and beyond, if nothing else.

Comment: For the record, Hubbard states that anyone who reads this screenplay without becoming a fully accredited scientologist is likely to suffer from a broken back, knee and arm and then die of pneumonia. And no, I'm not just making this up; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wall_of_Fire_(Scientology)

Comment: @JimmyShelter - Your sympathy is appreciated.

Comment: @JimmyShelter - You'll be pleased to hear that I didn't die of pneumonia despite reading the screenplay.

Comment: Five years on and still not dead.

Comment: Nine years and counting. I had a mild cold last year, but no pneumonia. If anything my back has gotten a bit better since I started cycling.